# Intuition behind duality principle?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm looking for an intuitive explanation of the duality principle. I found this [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Duality_Principle_(Boolean_Algebras)) but it was way above my head, considering I just started Boolean Algebra a couple of days ago.

I suspect most proofs will be above my head, so can someone help me see the intuition behind this principle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How I think about this is that given a Boolean algebra $(B,\wedge,\vee,\top,\bot)$, there's another Boolean algebra structure on the same set given by $(B,\vee,\wedge,\bot,\top)$. And these two Boolean algebras are isomorphic! What's the isomorphism? $b\mapsto \neg b$, naturally. So dualizing a theorem is just rewriting it in an isomorphic Boolean algebra that happens to have *suspiciously* similar-looking symbols.

**Edit:** Let's see if we can say this in more elementary terms. Boolean algebra has axioms: $\bot\implies \phi=\top, a\wedge(b\vee c)=(a\wedge b)\vee (a\wedge c)$ and so on. The duality principle just points out that for every one of these axioms, there's another one with $\bot$ exchanged for $\top$ and $\wedge$ exchanged for $\vee$. So in my first example: $\bot\implies \phi=\neg \bot \vee \phi$ switches to $\neg \top\wedge \phi=\neg(\top \vee \neg \phi)$ so we get $\neg(\top\vee \neg\phi)=\bot$, i.e. $\top\vee\neg\phi=\top,$ i.e. $\phi\implies \top$. For the second example, we get $a\vee(b\wedge c)=(a\vee b)\wedge(a\vee c)$, the other distributive law. And the duality principle holds in general just because *all* the axioms of Boolean algebra pair up in this way with a "dual" axiom, so that all theorems pair up with a dual theorem-just by dualizing every step in a proof.

Comment: Woah, way over my head! What do you mean by "a" Boolean Algebra? What's a Boolean Algebra "structure"? What's an isomorphism?

Comment: Oops, sorry for pitching that so badly. Let me try and edit.

Comment: Edited. Let me know if that's better.

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks for the help! I'll give you the bounty as soon as the minimum 24 hour wait is up.

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to be intuitive, so I'll try to stay away from the formalism.

Let's pretend that I am **not** a cat **and** **not** a dog. This is exactly the same as saying that I am **neither** a cat **nor** a dog. Essentially, we swap some symbols in a specific way and the result is equivalent to original. Symbolically, we could say

$$\neg(\text{Robin is a cat})\vee\neg(\text{Robin is a dog})\iff \neg((\text{Robin is a cat})\wedge(\text{Robin is a dog})).$$

So, everything that was unnegated is negated, and everything that was negated became unnegated. Think of it like applying the word "not" to everything. If I said I am not not a dog, I'm saying I am a dog, because I've unnegated the negation. Simultaneously, the "or" ($\wedge$) and the "and" ($\vee$) have been switched.

And that's my intuitive version of boolean duality.

Comment: @dfg You're welcome.